# RxJS 6 - Angular 6 - Properly canceling current http request if a new one is triggered

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I know this is totally possible but I have never used RxJs any more than simple http get and subscribes. I have a service that is listening for WebSocket events, when 1 such event triggers, I make a call to an Api to load some data. If that websocket event triggers while 1 api is already in transit I want to cancel it and then restart a new api call. I am not sure if I am correctly using SwitchMap and I am lost of how to use Pipe with RxJs 6.

Is this the proper usage of SwitchMap and pipe to get my data? It seems to be working right when triggering a large amount of events, but seems to have a long delay after the last event has triggered however that may be server lag because my api server is also my websocket server.

My Component:

```
clients: Client[] = [];

  constructor(public statsApi: StatisticsService)
  {
    this.statsApi.OnClientUpdate.pipe(switchMap(x => { return this.statsApi.GetClients() })).subscribe(x =>
    {
      console.log(x);
      this.LoadClients(x);
    });
  }

  private LoadClients(clients:Client[] = null): void
  { 
    if (clients != null)
    { 
      this.clients = clients;
    } else
    { 
      this.statsApi.GetClients().subscribe(data =>
      {
        this.clients = data;
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.LoadClients();
  }
```

GetClients inside of Service:

```
public GetClients(): Observable<Client[]>
  { 
    return this.http.get<Client[]>('http://localhost:5000/api/client');
  }
```

`OnClientUpdate returns an Observable<number>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is describing the process of sending an http request each time your `OnClientUpdate` observable yields. Each yield ends up selecting an observable which represents an http request. `switchMap` will subscribe to that http request observable and dispose of it's subscription to any prior http request observable. If that observable's subscription properly implements the disposal of the http request, `switchMap` will work as intended.

However, depending on how often `OnClientUpdate` *can* yield, you may want to add a `debounce` operation, thus preventing rapid-fire http request and cancellations.

Example - `don't spam, cancel all but the latest request, and yield each latest result`:

```
var latestHttpRequestResult =
    trigger
        .pipe(debounce(200))
        .pipe(switchMap(sendHttpRequestAsObservable));
```

Comment: I added a debounceTime now and it has made that screen load even smoother. In a typical use case the client update shouldn't be triggering very often. However, for testing purposes I am opening 20+ tabs which fires 20 client update events and then refreshing them all at once to see how that component handles it.